# Accessing array value by direct passing value of another array in string

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to access the array value by passing the value of another array element in the string.

Here is the example.

```
$arr = array("asif", "ali");
$arr2 = array("asif" => 3, "ali" => 5);

echo "value of data $arr2[$arr[0]]";
```

It is giving me the error as

> syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']'

I tried to access the value out of the string like the following.

```
$arr = array("asif", "ali");
$arr2 = array("asif" => 3, "ali" => 5);

echo $arr2[$arr[0]];
```

It is working fine.

Then I tried to use just a single array in the string and pass the other array's element value by variable.

```
$arr = array("asif", "ali");
$arr2 = array("asif" => 3, "ali" => 5);

$name = $arr[0];

echo "value of data $arr2[$name]";
```

It is also working fine.

Is there something wrong in the syntax?

Comment: it's not a bug, you just need wrap it in curly braces if you want it interpolated in the quoted string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [complex syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to expand arrays like that.

Change this:

```
echo "value of data $arr2[$arr[0]]";
```

To this:

```
echo "value of data {$arr2[$arr[0]]}";
```